# sqlcmd returning NUL instead of NULL for tinyint column

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -E -d MyDatabase -Q "sp_helpsubscription" -s "," -o file.csv -W -u
```

Column 23 which is suppose to be a tinyint (subscriber_type) is output as NUL instead of NULL when the value is NULL.

I cannot figure out why it's doing this or a way to fix it.  When I run sp_helpsubcription in SSMS the column contains the expected full NULL text.

In order to replication this you need a replicated database with a publication in at least one subscription to it.  This particular issue is with a transactional publication.

It does this even if I output the results to the screen instead of to a file.

Edit: The reason I'm doing this is because I can't issue an INSERT #TEMP EXEC sp_helpsubcription because of a NESTED EXEC INSERT inside sp_helppublication.

Comment: There is a (max_column_width = 3) setting or similar hidden somewhere that cuts the output that is longer than 3 chars?

Comment: I ended up using a Powershell script to get rid of the NULL and NUL values since I was going to BULK INSERT the results back into a table.  Ex: (get-content $FILE) | foreach-object {$_ -replace ",NUL[L]*", ","} | set-content $FILE

Comment: ypercube, I don't believe so since every other column that has NULL values is displayed correctly as NULL.  It's only this one column.

Comment: Right but only this column is `tinyint`, which can hold values from **0** up to **255**. i.e. numbers with up to 3 digits only.

Comment: So is there a way to make it NULL instead of NUL?  Not that it matters anymore, but I'm still curious.

Comment: Column name < 4 chars? Enlarge the length of the name

Answer (score 1):

`sqlcmd` only displays as many characters in a column as the width of the column data or the width of the column name, whichever is longer. You can expect the same behavior with the following data types:

- `bit`
- `tinyint`
- `decimal` with precision < 2
- `varchar` with length < 4

To work around the issue you can either cast the column to a longer data type or rename the column to a longer name.